# Where is Document Object Model (DOM) going in the next 2-3 years? What core concepts should we know about DOM?

Tags: html

what are some of the tools that I should know?

This is one of my question to get a quick round up from the community and get up-to-speed about the latest.

I know the basic definition that is

"The Document Object Model is an API for HTML and XML documents. It provides a structural representation of the document, enabling you to modify its content and visual presentation. Essentially, it connects web pages to scripts or programming languages. "

I am more interested in finding where it will go in the coming years..

Comment: We? Are you asking on behalf of a group or is this not really a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could follow what is going on with XHTML 2.0 and also Javascript 2.0. If you get the latest version of Firefox (3.1) you will have Javascript 1.8 which will help you see what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM

Comment: This was posted before the question was completely changed.

Comment: sorry I am still giving you +1, I had to edit the question to capture what is in my head.

Answer (score 1):

There are different DOMs: XML DOM, DHTML DOM... and so on. Please be more specific!
Any way, you must think in Javascript in each case.